# javax.mail work on PC but not on server

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I've search but can't seem to find a similar problem, never mind an answer.  I have a web app running on my laptop (windows 8), tomcat7 and it works fine. It sends out the email as expected.  I have the same code running on my linux server, also tomcat7 and I get `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`.

I've done the Authenticator thing from the start:

```
...
Authenticator mailAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.user"),
                                      properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.password"));
    }
};
try {
    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, mailAuthenticator);

    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    mimeMessage.setSubject("Subject, whoot whoot!");
    mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.from")));

    //This is an overkill
    List<String> emailList = new LinkedList<>();
    emailList.add("email@example.com");
    for(String item : emailList) {
        mimeMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(item));
    }

    //The body ).(
    StringBuilder sbMsg = new StringBuilder("Some text, etc.\n");
    sbMsg.append("more text");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
    BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart1.setContent(sbMsg.toString(), "text/plain");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
    mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);

    Transport transport = session.getTransport(properties.getProperty("mail.transport"));
    int port = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.port"));
    //Exception happens on the line below
    transport.connect(properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"),
                      port,
                      properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.user"),
                      properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.password"));
    transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Pokemon exception handling :(
    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while sending email", e);
}
```

The exception happens on `transport.connect`, and there is no description with the exception :(

I've checked the `mail.smtp.user` and `mail.smtp.password` and it is exactly the same :s

Any clues where I can start looking?

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace? Does your server firewall block certain ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got an emails and text from Google.  GMail thought I was trying to hack my account. I'm glad there is a logical answer to this problem :-)